# How can I prevent the alarm app from sounding during a phone call on iOS?

Tags: ios, call, alarm

Is it possible to configure the alarm app from sounding during a phone call?

This is extremely annoying that the alarm app sounds during a call.

This is loud and you have to ask the other party to wait while you finally disable it.